# CPQ - What does Calculate button do in QLE

Tags: cpq

In CPQ, Quote Line Editor, we are currently having an issue that when user add some bundle products, the price is correct. But when we change the start date in it and click calculate, the price becomes a different random number.

This only happens in our prod environment and not happening in sandboxes. I believe this is a salesforce bug. But might need to investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug I'm not sure need to look more in detail into all the other dependencies. After manually verify that it's still a random number you might want to raise a case with support! but the Salesforce CPQ applies price calculations to your quote, including all relevant price rules and product rules.

> When you click [**calculate button**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_use_the_qle.htm&type=5) all it does is simply recalculates your quote’s
>   prices after you make any changes.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think we have compared the price rules between the prod and sandboxes. Nothing was modified before the incident is happening. It is quite strange

Comment: @LanceShi Well looks like you need to raise a case for support then!